# how to use block i/o protocol in my uefi bootloader

Tags: freebsd, bootloader, uefi

I am reading FreeBSD uefi bootloader. But there is a part I can't understand about Block I/O Protocol.I quote source code.

```
status = systab->BootServices->LocateHandle(ByProtocol,
    &BlockIoProtocolGUID, NULL, &nparts, handles);
nparts /= sizeof(handles[0]);

for (i = 0; i < nparts; i++) {
    status = systab->BootServices->HandleProtocol(handles[i],
        &DevicePathGUID, (void **)&devpath); 
    if (EFI_ERROR(status))
        continue;

    while (!IsDevicePathEnd(NextDevicePathNode(devpath)))
        devpath = NextDevicePathNode(devpath);

    status = systab->BootServices->HandleProtocol(handles[i],
        &BlockIoProtocolGUID, (void **)&blkio); 
    if (EFI_ERROR(status))
        continue;

    if (!blkio->Media->LogicalPartition)
        continue;

    if (domount(devpath, blkio, 1) >= 0)
        break;
}
```

Why as below the code is searching device path end?

> ```
>   while (!IsDevicePathEnd(NextDevicePathNode(devpath)))
>         devpath = NextDevicePathNode(devpath);
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just want to add a bit to what haggai_e said. DP (device path) is a simple linked list where each node represents sort of a description of a physical or logical device in UEFI environment. And as you probably know each device in UEFI is a handle. So traversing through DP and getting the handle of the particular node gives you a handle to a particular device that DP describes.

Comment: I don't think that is accurate. As far as I know, device path nodes don't contain handles. You get a device path from a handle by using the device path protocol like the code in the question does.

Comment: Yes, my statement was not scientifically correct! DP node doesn't contain handles it describes the device or part of it. DP may have only one node and you can get handle from that DP. And you can go both ways: get DP from a handle or visa versa get a handle from a device path (which you can construct by yourself) or from part of it. This is how, for example, you have a DP for a logical partition and splitting the DP into parts you can get handles for partition, whole HDD, AHCI controller, etc...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the code wants to look at the last node of the device path, so it skips all the nodes until it reaches the one before the end node.